# Ler arquivo quando existir em diretório

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou construindo uma aplicação que lê um arquivo em um determinado diretório, porém este arquivo vai ser gerado neste diretório em momentos diferentes a partir de uma outra aplicação, depois que a aplicação consumir e processar os dados o arquivo é apagado, só que não sei como posso fazer com que minha aplicação processe quando este arquivo chegue no diretório.

Comment: Há duas situações possiveis que você não deixou claro qual delas quer tratar: você quer checar apenas se o arquivo existe e executar uma ação com ele ou você quer que seu aplicativo monitore certa pasta até que o arquivo seja criado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Montei um exemplo baseado no tutorial da [**WatchingService API**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Os comentários no código explicam o que cada comando faz e deve dar uma boa ideia de como processar os arquivos dentro de um cenário parecido com o descrito na pergunta.

O código:

```
//define pasta a ser observada
Path pastaOrigem = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("origem"));
//define pasta onde os arquivos sendo processados serão movidos
Path pastaProcessando = Files.createDirectories(pastaOrigem.resolve("processando"));
//define pasta onde os arquivos já processados serão movidos
Path pastaProcessados = Files.createDirectories(pastaOrigem.resolve("processados"));

//monitor da pasta
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

//registra para receber eventos de criação de arquivos no diretório
pastaOrigem.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);

//loop infinito
while (true) {

    WatchKey wk = null;
    try {
        //aguarda algum evento ocorrer
        System.out.printf("Aguardando arquivos em %s", pastaOrigem);
        wk = watcher.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    //percorre eventos recebidos
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {

        //ignora se ocorreu um problema
        if (event.kind() == OVERFLOW) continue;

        //pega nome do arquivo criado
        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
        Path nomeArquivo = ev.context();
        Path arquivoOrigem = pastaOrigem.resolve(nomeArquivo);
        System.out.printf("Arquivo criado: %s\n", arquivoOrigem);


        //move arquivo para "processando"
        Path arquivoProcessando = pastaProcessando.resolve(nomeArquivo);
        System.out.printf("Movendo para: %s\n", arquivoProcessando);
        Files.move(arquivoOrigem, arquivoProcessando);

        //processa arquivo
        System.out.printf("Processando arquivo %s\n", arquivoProcessando);

        //move para "processados"
        Path arquivoProcessado = pastaProcessados.resolve(nomeArquivo);
        System.out.printf("Movendo para: %s\n", arquivoProcessado);
        Files.move(arquivoProcessando, arquivoProcessado);

    }

    //prepara o próximo evento ou sai caso algum erro ocorra, como o diretório não existir mais
    if (!wk.reset()) {
        break;
    }
}

//encerramento manual, caso neccesário
//watcher.close();
```

Há duas coisas a se considerar não relativas diretamente a esta API:

1. No exemplo acima, os arquivos criados no diretório monitorado são movidos depois para um diretório `processando` e `processados`. Isso é feito para diminuir problemas onde o mesmo arquivo possa ser lido mais de uma vez, por exemplo. Além disso, se ocorrer um erro durante o processamento do arquivo, ele pode ser movido para uma pasta `erro` para que se possa então analisar o que ocorreu. Esta é apenas uma sugestão de como tratar o fluxo de leitura do arquivo e evitar deixar tudo numa pasta só, o que pode causar muitos problemas.
2. Um ponto a se considerar é **não gerar arquivos diretamente no diretório observado**. Se o sistema que gera o arquivo fizer isso, o arquivo pode ser lido no momento da criação, **antes** do sistema completar a escrita até o final. Então o ideal é colocar um arquivo num diretório temporário e então **mover** o arquivo para o diretório monitorado depois da geração ou transferência do mesmo estar totalmente concluída. De preferência, tenha algum mecanismo para validar se o arquivo lido é consistente e evite surpresas (como importações pela metade).